# Why doesn't inoremap work in this case

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, normal-mode

I'm coding c++ with vim and I want to set a shortcut while typing parenthesis and new line. Here is an example,

```
if (a == 1) {}|  // the cursor is at the end of the line and the vim is under INSERT mode
```

What I need is to set a shortcut to make this piece of code as below:

```
if (a == 1) {
    |  // the cursor is here now and the vim is under INSERT mode
}
```

I've tried like this:

```
inoremap <C-v><Enter> <C-o>i<CR><C-o>O
```

But with this setting, if I type `<C-v><C-Enter>`, the code will become:

```
if (a == 1) {}
|    // the cursor is here now and the vim is under INSERT mode
```

I'm confused now. Because I've tested with my vim and it should work.

```
if (a == 1) {}|   // the cursor is here with INSERT mode
```

Typing `<C-o>i`: `if (a == 1) {|}  // the cursor is here now with INSERT mode`
Then, typing `CR<C-o>O` could make the code become what I expected:

```
if (a == 1) {
    |  // the cursor is here with INSERT mode
}
```

As you see, it worked as expected, but why can't it work with `inoremap`?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107469/discussion-on-question-by-yves-why-doesnt-inoremap-work-in-this-case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about of simply using the following?

```
:inoremap <buffer> µ <left><cr><esc>O
```

PS: in my bracketing plugin, I test on `<cr>` whether my cursor is between brackets to trigger that behaviour (without the left part as I start from `{|}` instead.

Comment: You see, my issue is that the cursor is at the end of line, instead of between brackets. I tried `inoremap <C-v><Enter> <left><cr><esc>O`, but it's not working... So weird...

Comment: You see, when we code in vim, switching from INSERT mode to NORMAL mode will move the cursor to left. You can try like this: `i <esc> i <esc> i <esc> ...` and you will find that the cursor is moving towards the left. But it doesn't seem to work in shortcut settings...

Comment: That's extremely odd add I tested my mapping with `µ` and `<c-v><enter>` (which I think is a bad idea as `<c-v>` can be extremely useful), and it works from `toto {}|$`

Comment: So weird. It's not working here... I give up  :(

Comment: I removed all plugins from the `~/.vim/bundle/`, and I found the imap worked. Then I re-added the plugins one by one and tested for each adding, the imap always worked. Finally, I re-added all of my plugins and the imap still worked... That's weird but at least this issue disappear...